# Should I be honest in a yes or no question regarding lifting X amount of pounds?

Tags: resume

So I've filled out some job forms and when it came to one question regarding lifting something, I answered no cause it was much too heavy for me. So the question was,

> Are you capable of lift 75lbs repeatedly?

I of course cannot lift that much so I answered no, but I wonder if they think I'm too weak to do the job because that amount is much more than I can lift. I maybe can lift 30lbs though never tested on exactly what i can lift. Should I be honest, or should I say yes and then clarify on the interview?

Comment: Just by the way, typically around 50 lbs is considered the maximum safe unassisted lifting weight. Sounds like the job is quite physical in its nature.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie 50 pounds? Seems awfully light, is that one hand?

Comment: **Should I be honest, or should I say yes and then clarify on the interview?** - Clarify what? That you lied on the form? That doesn't sound like a good plan. Don't lie.

Comment: @Kilisi I was also under the impression 50 lbs was a standard "maximum" weight for repeated lifting, based on my past jobs as a carpenter and package handler. Of course in both roles I sometimes had to lift far more, but I think there may be some OSHA standard that considers 50 lbs being an upper limit for "repeated" lifting, whatever that might mean.

Comment: As a former Parks seasonal, 50 pounds was what we were required to be able to lift. 75 would require a team lift, unless you're a weight lifter.

Comment: @electronpusher ok, different experiences then I guess. As a forestry worker I'd lift double that routinely just shouldering logs around. But I'm old, back in the day I think they may have had a different idea of heavy lifting

Comment: @Kilisi Here in Australia, the law doesn't set a specific weight, but guidance from [Safe Work Australia](https://www.safeworkaustralia.gov.au/system/files/documents/1702/nationalcodeofpractice_manualhandling_nohsc2005-1990_archivepdf.pdf) recommends that nobody should be lifting more than 55 kg (approx. 120 lbs) unassisted. That assumes everything else is favourable; there have been cases here where employers were held liable for injuries from lifting as little as 12 kg when there were other risk factors involved e.g. twisting while lifting.

Comment: Information request: is this a position where lifting 75 lbs could reasonably be expected to be part of the job? This might be reasonable for something like a warehouse job, but if I saw this on an office job I'd be wondering whether it was an attempt to circumvent sex/disability-based discrimination laws.

Comment: Lift with your legs, now with your arms or back. Also, lifting something and walking with it are two different things. And something like a barbell which is made to be lifted versus a clunky box makes a huge difference. Are you saying you are unable to carry a  bag of potatoes in each hand and walk at the same time? That you need both hands to carry one bag of potatoes? If so, that would be a problem at any job that isn't a desk job.

Comment: @electronpusher 50 pounds is a recommended max lift for a single person, but there are no regulations in the US that prevent an employer from requiring more.

Comment: What kind of job? Loading trucks? Carrying farm animals?

Comment: They probably overstate the maximum - you might never be required 75lb but they want to know you are capable of it so you'll be comfortable or won't struggle with the weight you will be required to lift which might be a little bit lighter but still quite heavy.

Answer (score 5):

Being honest on the application form is always the best policy.

You can write on the application form that you can lift 30 pounds if that is truly the max you can handle. If they are interested, then they will call you.

However, I think that, unless there are some special health issues or special circumstances,  most average and generally healthy people (both men and women) can likely lift more than 30 pounds.

You mentioned that you are not sure what is the maximum weight you can actually lift. So, if you are one of the average and generally healthy people, I would recommend that you try to lift some weights inside your home or gym **to measure or verify the max weight you can lift**, and report a more accurate number in the job application.

Comment: Agreed, but that said, there's a difference between "could" and "should", and it depends on more factors than just the weight involved. Somebody who can comfortably lift a 75-lb weight at the gym might well be at risk of injury lifting 75-lb boxes with no handles, in a position that requires twisting or holding the box far away from their body.

Comment: I think most people are overlooking the most crucial part of that description. "repeatedly". It gives no indication how often during the day he actually would have to lift that.

Comment: Sebastian, and after doing this for ten years, will you still be a healthy man?

Comment: Nowhere did Octavio say they were grown or a man. For all we know they're a high school girl applying for a job at a restaurant. I worked at a kebab shop that regularly had me lift 50lbs worth of frozen kebab meat. I had female high school coworkers who couldn't do that portion of the job and the owners always made sure there was at least 1 person at the store who could.

Also, they could have some sort of disability preventing them from heavy lifting, like fine motor control problems or chronic pain

Comment: Over here in Germany, the work accident insurance (also responsible for work-related illness) score load lifting/carrying according to a whole bunch of factors (even to "being new to the profession"). However, they consider 40 kg for healthy males age 21 - 40 (25 kg for females) loads where even a single handling may come at a substantial heath risk. The required 34 kg *could* still be in the range of what is unlikely to be too strenuous for an adult male if the lifting is done ergnomically and is < 10x per day lifting or < 5 min holding or < 300 m carrying...